# correct select statement for multiple tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the latest 5 titles from 3 tables, I think I might be going wrong somewhere in my statement.

Here is my statement

```
SELECT * FROM news N, blog B, comments C WHERE active='1' ASC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

After `FROM` you can only set 1 table where the results will come from. Moreover if you use keyword `ASC` you should also say the field you `order by` try:

```
SELECT * FROM news  WHERE active='1' order by 'fieldnew' ASC 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM blog  WHERE active='1' order by 'fieldblog' ASC) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM comments  WHERE active='1' order by 'fieldcommnet' ASC)
```

Comment: But I need the titles from 3 tables and they have to show up on a page together, if that makes sense

Comment: You need the table names or the fields of tables?

Comment: my table names are news, blog and comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a join on three tables provided !

in sql-server:

```
select top 5 * from
(
select * from News N inner join blog B on N.id=B.id inner join comments C on C.id=N.id
)x

order <something>
```

Comment: I get this error when I try your code 
Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/classes/Page.php on line 2346  on that line is while( $result = mysql_fetch_object($query)){